# How to get Flask camera feed to server from client

Tags: python, flask, deployment, mediapipe

I know nothing of Back-end Web development I just registered for a  just for fun hackathon now My app works fine on local machine but when i deploy it on the server it fails to get the camera feed`
Given Below is the app.py file base.html ExecersicebicepCurl.html and bicepcurl.py
**this is app.py**

```
import time
import cv2 
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
 
from project import exerciseAI, yogaAI  

#-----------------Routing----------------------------------

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/exercise/biceps-curl')
def exerciseBicepsCurl():      
    return render_template('exerciseBicepsCurl.html')    
 
@app.route('/exercise/push-ups') 
def exercisePushUps():       
    return render_template('exercisePushUps.html')       

@app.route('/exercise/squats')  
def exerciseSquats():       
    return render_template('exerciseSquats.html')   

@app.route('/yoga/t-pose')
def yogaT():
    return render_template('yogaT.html') 

@app.route('/yoga/tree-pose')    
def yogaTree():          
    return render_template('yogaTree.html')  

@app.route('/yoga/warrior-pose')      
def yogaWarrior():          
    return render_template('yogaWarrior.html')  

@app.route('/about')  
def about(): 
    return render_template('about.html')  


#-----------------Video-Feeds--------------------------------- 
  
@app.route('/bicepCurl_feed')  
def bicepCurl_feed(): 
    return Response(exerciseAI.bicepCurl.gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') 

@app.route('/pushUps_feed')  
def pushUps_feed(): 
    return Response(exerciseAI.pushUps.gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') 
   
@app.route('/squats_feed')    
def squats_feed(): 
    return Response(exerciseAI.squats.gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') 

@app.route('/tPose_feed') 
def tPose_feed(): 
    return Response(yogaAI.tPose.gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')  

@app.route('/treePose_feed')  
def treePose_feed():  
    return Response(yogaAI.treePose.gen() ,mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')         
 
@app.route('/warriorPose_feed')                  
def warriorPose_feed():    
    return Response(yogaAI.warriorPose.gen() ,mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')         
 
#--------------------------------------------------------------
app.run(debug=True, host ='0.0.0.0')
```

**bicepCurl.py**

```
from . import *   
from .util import *    

def gen():
    previous_time = 0
    # creating our model to draw landmarks
    mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    # creating our model to detected our pose
    my_pose = mp.solutions.pose
    pose = my_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.7,min_tracking_confidence=0.5)
    counter = 0 
    stage = None
    flag = False
    half = 10
    text=""
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5,min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, img = cap.read()
        # converting image to RGB from BGR cuz mediapipe only work on RGB
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        result = pose.process(imgRGB)
        # print(result.pose_landmarks)
        if result.pose_landmarks:
            flag = True if counter%2 == 0 else False
            landmarks = result.pose_landmarks.landmark
            if flag:
                shoulder = [landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow = [landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist = [landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]
            else:
                shoulder = [landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                elbow = [landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x,landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y]
                wrist = [landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x,landmarks[my_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y]
            angle = calculate_angle(shoulder,elbow,wrist)
            if angle > 160:
                stage = "down"
            if angle < 30 and stage =='down':
                stage="up"
                counter +=1
            cv2.putText(img, str(angle), 
                           tuple(np.multiply(elbow, [640, 480]).astype(int)), 
                           cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 180, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                                )
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, result.pose_landmarks, my_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                mpDraw.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), 
                                mpDraw.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))

        # checking video frame rate
        # current_time = time.time()
        # fps = 1 / (current_time - previous_time)
        # previous_time = current_time

        # Writing FrameRate on video
        if(counter==0):
            cv2.putText(img, str(int(counter)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        elif(counter != 0 and  counter%20)==0:
            cv2.putText(img, str("Good Job"), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        else:
            cv2.putText(img, str(int(counter)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        
        #cv2.imshow("Pose detection", img)
        frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27: 
            break
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title> 
    <meta name="description" content=""> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/release/v5.8.1/css/all.css"> 
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dialog.css') }}">  
    {% block head %}      

    {% endblock %}       
    <style>
                /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
                .dropdown-content {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                min-width: 160px;
                box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  
                z-index: 1;
                margin-top: 13px;  
                }

                /* Links inside the dropdown */
                .dropdown-content a {
                color: black;
                padding: 12px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block; 
                }

                /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
                .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

                /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
                .show {display:block;}  
    </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- <h1 class="title">FitHub</h1>     --> 
        <img width="255px" height="90px" src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/newlogo.png')}}" alt="">  
        <p class="tagline">Fit You, Happy You</p>
        <img style="filter: invert(1);" height="90px" width="100px" class="im" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo1.png') }}"> 
    </header>        


    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/" class="tb"><b>HOME</b></a></li>     
            <li>  
                <a href="#" onclick="dropdownExercise()"><b>EXERCISE</b></a>      
                <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">     
                    <a href="/exercise/biceps-curl">Bicep-Curl</a> 
                    <a href="/exercise/push-ups">Push-Ups</a>       
                    <a href="/exercise/squats">Squats</a>  
                </div>           
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="dropdownYoga()"><b>YOGA</b></a>    
                <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content"> 
                    <a href="/yoga/t-pose">T Pose</a>       
                    <a href="/yoga/tree-pose">Tree Pose</a>     
                    <a href="/yoga/warrior-pose">Warrior Pose</a> 
                </div>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="/about"><b>ABOUT</b></a></li>        
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script>
            function dropdownExercise() {        
            document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
            } 
            function dropdownYoga() { 
            document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
            } 
    </script>
    {% block content %}      

    {% endblock %}   
</body> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function closeVideo() { 
                var iframe = document.getElementById('video-iframe');
                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);  
            }    
            function openVideo(activity) {
                var div = document.getElementById('div-1'); 
                div.innerHTML = `         
                <iframe id="video-iframe" style="border:2px solid #fc6d6d;" src="/${activity}" width="640" height="480"></iframe> 
                `;  
            }  
        </script>      
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**exerciseBicepsCurl.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}      

{% endblock %}  


{% block content %} 
   

<div class="popup-overlay">    
  <div class="popup">       
    <div class="pophead">          
      <h2><b>HERE ARE THE STEP-BY-STEP INSTRUCTIONS FOR BICEPS CURLS:</b></h2>
    </div>   
    <p style="margin-top:40px; text-align: left; font-size: large; margin-left: 40px;"> 
      1. Stand with feet shoulder-width apart and palms facing forward holding a dumbbell. <br><br>
      2. Keeping elbows close to the body, slowly raise one dumbbell towards the shoulder while keeping the wrist straight.<br><br>
      3. Pause and contract the bicep at the top of the movement, then lower the dumbbell back down to the starting position.<br><br>
      4. Repeat the movement with the other arm and continue alternating for desired reps.<br><br>  
      5. Breathe naturally and avoid swinging the arms or using momentum to lift the weight.<br><br>
      6. Start with lighter weights and gradually increase as strength improves.<br><br>  
    </p>         
    <button class="pop-btn1" id="popup-button"><b>OK</b></button>  
    <button  class="pop-btn2" id="popup-button"><b>CLOSE</b></button>    
  </div>       
</div> 
   
<!--  -->
 
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><b>BICEP-CURLS</b></h1>    
<div style="justify-content: center; display: flex; margin-top: -30px;"> 
    <div id="div-1" class="div-1">        
        <!-- code --> 
    </div>              
    <div id="div-2" class="div-2">               
        <img class="camera-0" width="640px" height="360px" src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/gifs/ezgif-2-6976e23002.gif')}}" alt="">      
    </div>  
</div>  

  <div class="center" id="div-3" style="margin-left: 20rem;">
    <div class="btn btn2">
      <div class="inner"></div>    
      <button id="b1" onclick="openVideo('bicepCurl_feed')"><b>START</b> </button>
    </div> 
  <div class="btn btn1">
    <div class="inner"></div>  
    <button id="b1" onclick="closeVideo()"><b>FINISH</b></button>
  </div> 
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

I wanted to count the reps of my curl exercise code servers its purpose on the local machine but when I deployed it on google cloud (amd) Linux server it dose not open the camera